# delay while using process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm dealing with a time sensitive problem where the time taken for execution is crucial. But now i'm facing a problem, StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); is taking more time to return the result and thus increasing the execution time. This is a portion of my code. To show the delay taken, I have printed the times at 3 places. The times are mentioned below the code.

```
 tsw.WriteLine("Time 1 :"+DateTime.UtcNow);

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
        /*REDIRECTING THE STANDARD INPUT TO  Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.*/
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        /*REDIRECTING THE STANDARD INPUT TO  Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.*/


        /*CREATING A PROCESS, ASSIGN ITS PROCESSINFO AND START IT*/
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        /*CREATING A PROCESS, ASSIGN ITS PROCESSINFO AND START IT*/

   tsw.WriteLine("Time 2 :" + DateTime.UtcNow);

        /* GETTING RESULT INTO A STRING*/
        result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.WaitForExit();

    tsw.WriteLine("Time 3 :" + DateTime.UtcNow);
```

The result is

`Time 1 :1/20/2016 6:37:57 AM
Time 2 :1/20/2016 6:37:57 AM
Time 3 :1/20/2016 6:38:02 AM`

As we could see, proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); is taking around 5 seconds to return and store in a string. Is this normal or something wrong with my code?Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Have you tried checking the time before calling WaitForExit?

Also have you tried it on more than one machine - different versions of Windows etc?  It may be a machine-specific issue.

Comment: Yes i've checked it before WaitForExit. But the result is still the same. Also we have checked it in different system, but no change.

Comment: How do you know the real end of a stream?  The sending end can always add more data.  The best method is to add a byte count to beginning of message.  Then read number of bytes until all bytes are received instead of reading to end.

Comment: It is pointless to call `WaitForExit()` after `ReadToEnd()`; the latter won't return until stdout has been closed, which won't happen until the process exits. As far as the question itself goes, if it takes 5 seconds for the process to end, that's the process itself, not the `Process` class. How long the process takes depends entirely on the process; that key piece of information is completely absent in the question, represented just by a variable named `command`. Please provide a good [mcve] if you want help.